# Converting a list into a data frame with specific titles

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list like this:

```
$20
[1] 500

$30
[2] 600
```

I want to convert this into a dataframe like this

```
id    values
20     500
30     600
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
L <- list(`20`=500,`30`=600)
df <- data.frame(id=names(L), values=sapply(L, function(x) x[1]))
# > df
#    id values
# 20 20    500
# 30 30    600
```

or a bit more tricky:

```
df <- data.frame(id=names(L), values=sapply(L, '[', 1))
```

Till now I was thinking about longer vectors (and take only the first element). But in your case (if each element of the list is only a 1-element vector) a shorter solution (thx to Abdou for the comment) is:

```
df <- data.frame(id = names(L), values = unlist(L))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `data.frame(id = names(L), values = unlist(L))` be shorter?

Comment: Yes, nice solution. I was thinking about longer vectors (and take only the first element).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do.call` to solve your problem:

```
li <- list(`20`=500,`30`=600)
df <- data.frame(Values = do.call("rbind",li))
df$Id <- rownames(df)
rownames(df) <- NULL
df <- df[,c(2,1)]
df
```

**Output:**

```
    > df
  Id Values
1 20    500
2 30    600
```

Answer (score 0):

purrr's `*_df` functions iterate a function over a list and simplify to a data.frame. With the development version, you can use the new `imap` variant that uses the names or indices as a second variable `.y`:

```r
library(purrr)

l <- list(`25` = 900, `26` = 500) 

l %>% imap_dfr(~data.frame(id = as.integer(.y), 
                           value = .x))
#>   id value
#> 1 25   900
#> 2 26   500
```

or with CRAN purrr, you can pass the names as the second variable to `map2`:

```r
l %>% map2_df(names(.), 
              ~data.frame(id = as.integer(.y), 
                          value = .x))
#>   id value
#> 1 25   900
#> 2 26   500
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to achieve the same by the use of `melt` function from `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
l = list('20'=500, '30'=600)
melt(as.data.frame(l, check.names = F))
```

Output:

```
    variable value
1      20   500
2      30   600
```

Alternate approach without using any package

```
ls = list('20' = 500, '30' = 600, '40' = 400)
d = data.frame('id' = row.names(as.array(unlist(ls))), 'value' = unlist(ls),row.names = 1:length(ls))
```

Output

```
    id value
1   20   500
2   30   600
3   40   700
4   50   800
```

Answer (score 0):

use unlist function.

```
L = list(`20`=500,`30`=600)
df = unlist(L)
```

It returns vector. If you want data.frame:

```
df = as.data.frame(t(unlist(L)))
```

Output:

```
> df
   20  30
1 500 600
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `Map`

```
l <- list(`20`=500,`30`=600)
do.call(rbind,Map(data.frame,id=names(l),values=l))

   id values
20 20    500
30 30    600
```